# Summation to Matrix

Tags: matrices

How would you represent the following in matrix notation?

$$
1 - \sum_{i}\sum_{j} w_i w_j p_{ij}
$$

Would the following be correct?

```
1-(W W' p)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hint: put $w_j$ at the right of $p_{i,j}$

Answer (score 2):

I guess $w=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)^T$ is the vector and $P$ is the matrix. Then, it is rather
$$1-(w^T P w)\,.$$
Expand it!

Comment: hi i forgot to mention that it is double summation. Sorry. Would that change the answer?